# Prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{x_i}\sqrt{x_i-x_{i-1}}\le\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n^2}\frac1i-\frac12$ for integers $1=x_0\le x_1\le x_2\le\cdots\le x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, contest-math, radicals

Suppose $x_{i}\in N^{+}$, and $1=x_{0}\le x_{1}\le x_{2}\le\cdots\le x_{n}$. Show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sqrt{x_{i}-x_{i-1}}}{x_{i}}\le\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\dfrac{1}{i}-\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Maybe it can be proved by using the C-S inequality. But I am unable to find a solution.

Comment: Why don't you add the source of this problem so as to fulfill the requirement for contextual information so that the problem, which a nice one in itself, can be re-opened? I actually do like to know which book this problem comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following can help.

Let for $n>1$ we have $x_n\leq n^2$.

Thus, $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{x_i-x_{i-1}}}{x_i}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i-x_{i-1}}{x_i}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{x_i-x_{i-1}}\frac{1}{x_i}\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{x_i-x_{i-1}}\frac{1}{x_{i-1}+j}=\sum_{i=x_0+1}^{x_n}\frac{1}{i}\leq\sum_{i=2}^{n^2}\frac{1}{i}<\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{2}.$$
If first $x_k>n^2$.

Thus, $$\sum_{i=k}^n\frac{\sqrt{x_i-x_{i-1}}}{x_i}<\sum_{i=k}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_i}}<\sum_{i=k}^n\frac{1}{n}<1$$ and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{\sqrt{x_i-x_{i-1}}}{x_i}<\sum_{i=2}^{n^2}\frac{1}{i}.$$

Comment: then How to do it?

Comment: @communnites For $x_n\leq n^2$ it's proven. Try to end the proof if $x_k>n^2$ for some $k<n$, where $x_{k-1}\leq n^2.$ The biggest part of the work I made already.

Comment: why $\sqrt{x_{i}-x_{i-1}}\le x_{i}-x_{i-1}$? if $x_{i}=x_{i-1}$ then?

Comment: and My question right is $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\dfrac{1}{i^2}-\frac{1}{2}$,not  $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\dfrac{1}{i^2}$

Comment: @communnites Because for all natural $m$ we have $\sqrt{m}\leq m.$ Also, for $x_n\leq n^2$ I proved that  $LHS\leq\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n^2}\frac{1}{i}<\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n^2}\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: If some $x_{i}=x_{i-1}$ it's just better because number of terms in the left sum is less than $n$ and we can assume that $1=x_0<x_1<x_2<...<x_n.$

Comment: Very nice approach as usual! There is a small gap in the proof though. For the case where $\exists k \ni x_k>n^2$, you have proved the upper bound to be $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}\dfrac1i$. It is $\dfrac12$ more than the required bound.

Comment: Thank you @Hans for your interest!

Comment: You are welcome. But are you going to plug the gap? :-)

Comment: I thought about this, but it still does not turn out.